# Fail to find OpenGraph tags with jSoup on some websites

Tags: java, html, jsoup, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to extract OpenGraph metadata from webistes to show the user a preview. I'm using jSoup, and in particular, I'm having problems extracting an image url. For some (or most, actually) websites that I've tested, the code below works just fine, but a handful are giving me problems. Most prominently YouTube. For example:
When using "Inspect Element" in Chrome for this page: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AskAQwOBvhc
my code returns null, while upon inspection I would expect to find
this:

```
"//s.ytimg.com/yts/img/youtube_logo_stacked-vfl225ZTx.png"
```

From the following line in the page head:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="//s.ytimg.com/yts/img/youtube_logo_stacked-vfl225ZTx.png">
```

But my code returns null, as opposed to when testing many other sites, like:
http://www.bbc.com/culture/story/20150304-is-house-of-cards-worth-watching
Where I do find the desired URL.

```
Document document = null; 
try {
    document = Jsoup.connect(Url).get();
} catch (IOException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String ogImage = null; 
Elements metaOgImage = document.select("meta[property=og:image]");

if (metaOgImage!=null) {
 ogDescription = metaOgImage.first().attr("content");
}
```

I've also tried iterating through the Elements to see if it my desired tag was simply not the first. I'm not overly familiar with HTML and web technologies, but I'm inclined to belive there is some distinct difference between the two sites that I've failed to recognize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, it appears I've solved it. The loaded document was not the same as when viewing in Chrome because the UserAgent was different. I changed:

```
document = Jsoup.connect(Url).get();
```

into:

```
document = Jsoup.connect(Url).userAgent(myUserAgent).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

If is possible to have more metaOgImage try this:

```
Elements metaOgImage = doc.getElementsByTag("meta");

for(Element og : metaOgImage){

   if((og.attr("property").toString()).equalsIgnoreCase("og:image")){

     ogDescription = og.attr("content").toString();

}
}
```